# yii2 ajax call no longer working after setting URL rules

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2

I setup ajax function that is called when a button is clicked.

It works when there no rule rules however when I set the below URL manager rules

```
'posts' => 'posts/index',
'posts/index' => 'posts/index',
'posts/view/<id:\d+>' => 'posts/view',    
'posts/<slug>' => 'posts/slug',
```

I get the following error

```
POST http://localhost:8888/posts/liked?id=56 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information so i am just assuming that your UrlManager config is like this.

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'rules' => [
            'posts' => 'posts/index',
            'posts/index' => 'posts/index',
            'posts/view/<id:\d+>' => 'posts/view',
            'posts/<slug>' => 'posts/slug',
            ...
```

Where `posts` is `PostsController` and `slug` is `actionSlug()`.

If your ajax request code is like below, it will work.

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/posts/liked?id=56',
            type: 'POST',
            ...
```

I have tested this using the action function below in `PostsController`.

```
public function actionSlug() {
    $id = Yii::$app->request->get('id');
    echo json_encode($id);
}
```